# Updating permissions on Amazon S3 files that were uploaded via JungleDisk

Tags: permissions, amazon-s3, jungledisk

I am starting to use Jungle Disk to upload files to an Amazon S3 bucket which corresponds to a Cloudfront distribution. i.e. I can access it via an http:// URL and I am using Amazon as a CDN.

The problem I am facing is that Jungle Disk doesn't set 'read' permissions on the files so  when I go to the corresponding URL in a browser I get an Amazon `'AccessDenied'` error. If I use a tool like BucketExplorer to set the ACL then that URL now returns a 200.

I really really like the simplicity of dragging files to a network drive. JungleDisk is the best program I've found to do this reliably without tripping over itself and getting confused. However it doesn't seem to have an option to make the files read-able.

I really don't want to have to go to a different tool (especially if i have to buy it) to just change the permissions - and this seems really slow anyway because they generally seem to traverse the whole directory structure.

JungleDisk provides some kind of 'web access' - but this is a paid feature and I'm not sure if it will work or not.

S3 doesn't appear to propagate permissions down which is a real pain.

I'm considering writing a manual tool to traverse my tree and set everything to 'read' but I'd rather not do this if this is a problem someone else has already solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* I am the developer of this tool, but I think it may answer your question.

If you are on Windows you can use [CloudBerry Explorer](http://cloudberrylab.com/) Amazon S3 client. It supports most of the Amazon S3 and CloudFront features and It is freeware.

Comment: looks promising - is this new? i just cant stand that stupid firefox plugin. incredibly buggy

Comment: It will be one year old soon ;-) I am so surprised so few users know about it.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit) Mac app to modify permissions on files I've already uploaded with JungleDisk.  If you're looking for a more cross-platform solution, the [S3Fox](http://www.s3fox.net) browser plugin for Firefox claims to be able to modify permissions on S3 files as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a web based tool, you can use [S3fm](http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3fm/index.html), free online Amazon S3 file manager.

It's a pure Ajax app that runs in your browser and doesn't require sharing your credentials with a 3rd party web site.

Comment: I just happened across this answer on google and I caution anyone who wants to use S3fm. You should use the s3 URL and SSL (https://) for the site, as the application is probably sending secure information across the wire.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a reliable cross-platform tool to handle permissions, you can have a look at [CrossFTP Pro](http://www.crossftp.com/). It supports most of the Amazon S3 and CloudFront features as well.